# MSBuild12 on a machine with only VS2015

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, visual-studio-2015

I am looking at setting up a teamcity on my local machine. I only have VS2015 installed on my machine. I believe this comes with MSBuild 14.0. However, teamcity is asking for version 12. If I try to install MS Build tools 2013, installation fails with not so legible error log.

Log from file:

```
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:47]i000: MUX:  Go to Welcome page.
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:47]i000: Setting string variable 'CEIPConsent' to value ''
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:47]i000: MUX:  User Feedback control is Selected because opt-in value is BundleOptOut
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:47]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[391C:3484][2015-06-12T17:18:47]i000: MUX:  User feedback control is Enable because opt-in value is NotDefined
[391C:3484][2015-06-12T17:18:49]i000: MUX:  User feedback control is Enable because opt-in value is NotDefined
[391C:3484][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i000: Setting string variable 'CustomInstallPath' to value 'C:\Program Files (x86)'
[391C:3484][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i000: MUX:  Current action: Install
[391C:3484][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i000: Setting string variable 'CurrentOperation' to value 'Install'
[391C:3484][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i000: MUX:  Go to Progress page.
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i300: Apply begin
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i000: MUX:  Apply Phase Begin
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i000: MUX:  -----------------
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i000: MUX:  Metrics: ShouldSendData=False
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i000: Setting string variable 'SqmOption' to value '0'
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:18:50]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space before install:  SystemDrive C:\ 9411219456 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 9411219456 bytes
[2AA8:1AAC][2015-06-12T17:18:52]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[2AA8:1AAC][2015-06-12T17:19:01]i361: Created a system restore point.
[2AA8:1AAC][2015-06-12T17:19:02]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\BANNB\AppData\Local\Temp\{2bceccd3-6613-4596-b748-441a06847696}\.be\BuildTools_Full.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2bceccd3-6613-4596-b748-441a06847696}\BuildTools_Full.exe'
[2AA8:1AAC][2015-06-12T17:19:02]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {2bceccd3-6613-4596-b748-441a06847696}, version: 12.0.21005.1
[391C:4C64][2015-06-12T17:19:02]i000: MUX:  Cache Begin
[391C:4C64][2015-06-12T17:19:03]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[391C:4C64][2015-06-12T17:19:03]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[391C:4C64][2015-06-12T17:19:03]i336: Acquiring container: WixAttachedContainer, copy from: C:\Users\BANNB\Downloads\BuildTools_Full.exe
[391C:4C64][2015-06-12T17:19:03]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'C:\Users\BANNB\Downloads\'
[391C:3284][2015-06-12T17:19:03]e000: Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract all files from container.
[391C:4C64][2015-06-12T17:19:03]e000: Error 0x80004005: Faild to begin and wait for operation.
[391C:4C64][2015-06-12T17:19:03]e000: Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract payload: a10 from container: WixAttachedContainer
[391C:4C64][2015-06-12T17:19:03]e312: Failed to extract payloads from container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Users\BANNB\AppData\Local\Temp\{2bceccd3-6613-4596-b748-441a06847696}\D1B74527320C660A977F05265F7F21C126A340D7, error: 0x80004005.
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:19:03]e000: Error 0x80004005: Cache thread exited unexpectedly.
[2AA8:1AAC][2015-06-12T17:19:03]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {2bceccd3-6613-4596-b748-441a06847696}
[2AA8:1AAC][2015-06-12T17:19:04]i352: Removing cached bundle: {2bceccd3-6613-4596-b748-441a06847696}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2bceccd3-6613-4596-b748-441a06847696}\
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:19:04]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 348581888  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 95793152
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:19:04]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 9315557376 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 9315557376 bytes
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:19:04]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147467259 (0x80004005), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=Apply Failure
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:19:04]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[391C:32DC][2015-06-12T17:19:04]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80004005, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Would appreciate any pointers.

thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors in Event Viewer? Specifically application log, look for MSI related errors.